# Transactions not working. Spring boot @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Transactional
    public boolean processStream(InputStream is) {
        ...
        myService.doIt(foo);
        ...
    }
}

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Lei doIt(Foo foo) {
        ...
        foo = em.merge(foo);
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that while the stream is processed the Foo objects are already committed to the database. I was hoping it would be committed when processStream is done.

Comment: Even with spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=MANUAL the Foo objects are visible immediately

Answer (score 0):

Got it: MyComponent::processStream() was called from MyComponent::processFile()

It seems that the @Transactional annotation is required on the ENTRY METHOD

This helps debugging:
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE